# Python flask_bcrypt generates a different hashed password every time

Tags: python-3.x, flask, hash, flask-login

I have a Python FLask app that uses Bcrypt from flask_bcrypt to hash the user's password during login. I hashed the user's password using Bcrypt and stored the hashed value in the MySQL database for the user. Then, when the user logs in, the form password is to be hashed and compared with the user's hashed pw from the database. However, when I run the above code the login fails because the hashed pw from the form always hashes to a different value. The user.password is what is stored in the database. I have the SECRET_KEY set in a config file. I thought the SECRET_KEY would provide a seed value to the hash function so that the hashed pw would always return the same value, but this isn't happening. What am I doing wrong?

Login attempt #1:
user.password: $2b$12$aBR1OcL8yUUfjSlw9JaJT.25rV9E2oN3qY6.1PpfrdarnVzKrTLHS
hashed_password: $2b$12$tNwenU3a3BT6N4RumFWipew9SlWvZzwsyZKJ3s5D2Pyaj9En/wkS.

Login attempt #1:
user.password: $2b$12$aBR1OcL8yUUfjSlw9JaJT.25rV9E2oN3qY6.1PpfrdarnVzKrTLHS
hashed_password: $2b$12$Hl6bCdW0NLF2iUCwTd0kGeFzUu0HeZ29m88d2GKH6l.a285U7HUQC

```
#app.py: 
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect, session
from flask_login import LoginManager, current_user
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from models import User
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_envvar("INVWEB_SETTINGS") #<<References SECRET_KEY
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    user = db.get_user_by_id(int(current_user.id))
    return user
    
    
#account_login.py:
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, render_template, url_for, request, flash, redirect
from flask_login import login_user
import db

@account_login_bp.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            hashed_password = app.bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
            user = db.get_user(form.username.data.upper())
            print(f"user.password: {user.password}")
            print(f"hashed_password: {hashed_password}")
            if app.bcrypt.check_password_hash(hashed_password, user.password):
                login_user(user)
                flash('Logged in successfully.')
                next_page = request.args.get('next')
                return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect(url_for('general_bp.index'))
            else:
                next_page = request.args.get('next')
                return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect(url_for('account_login_bp.login'))
        except Exception as e:
            return 'There was an issue with your authentication attempt'
    else:
        return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

Comment: I solved this issue. I thought you had to hash the password and then call app.bcrypt.check_password_hash(hashed_password, user.password)
However, that is incorrect. The correct way is to pass the hashed password from the database as the first parameter (user.password) and the non-hashed password from the login form as the 2nd parameter (form.password.data). 

app.bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data)

Answer (score 1):

As you have already realized, when you want to check a password hash, you have to pass the stored hash at your database and the password typed on the form, like this:

```
check_password_hash(Stored_hash, form_password)
```

the "generate_password_hash" function should only be used when you are creating a new user and storing its hash.

An important note: if your hash function is generating a different hash for the same password, it means that it uses "salt", which is a good sign, it is a technique built to increase the security of your passwords and its normal behavior.